# Which statement represents a line segment?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I have two points $A = [1,1]$ and $B = [3,-1]$ which forms a line segment.

The question is, which of the following statements represent a line segment given by  the points.

**a.)** $\{[1+t,1−t] \mid t\in⟨0,2⟩\}$

**b.)** $\{[x,y] \mid x\in\mathbb R \text{ and } y=2−x\}$

**c.)** $\{[s,2−s] \mid s∈⟨1,3⟩\}$

**d.)** $\{[s,t] \mid s\in⟨1,3⟩ \text{ and } t=2−s\}$

Any advice would be helpful thank you!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome. You'll notice that your question suddenly looks prettier, because Thomas Andrews edited it suing MathJax; if you click on "edit" below the question, you can see what was typed to make those pretty formulas. And you can use that as a chance to tell us what you've tried, and what are your thoughts on the problem so far, which lets us help you more effectively. If you show no effort in this direction, we're likely to show fairly little effort to help you. We're not a "let's do someone's homework for them" site.

Comment: Just to be clear: there are two very real possibilities here. One is that you don't really understand sets or set-constructor notation; another is that you don't understand affine combinations of points in the plane. Clearly, our answers will be very different depending on which of these you seem to be uncertain about.

Comment: I don´t really know what exactly b,c,d symbolize, i also think that b.) can´t be correct because  x ∈ R. Besides that i think c and d, means the same, but  I am not really sure.

Comment: Is it your instructor that use uncommon notations ? Usually points coordinates are between parentheses :  $A=(1,1)$ instead of $A=[1,1]$. Moreover, $s \in <1,3>$ should be $s \in [1,3]$. A hint : it is option d) that is the good one.

Comment: I think it comes from an idea how would you describe a segment line such as X= a1 +t, while t ∈ <o,1> so "s" is some kind of variable. But aren´t the options d and c the same?

Comment: yes, options c and d are the same. So maybe the answer to "which" is "both c and d"...or maybe there are still others that also work. Maybe the answer is "all of them". The word "which"  is not necessarily singular. (The use of "represent" rather than "represents" suggests that there are two or more correct answers.)

Comment: Yes i think, more of them are correct, so i think its all of them, except the second one which represent a regular straight line